# Angular TypeError: "Media.Search is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know a similar question has been asked before, but I couldn't find a solution that worked for my situation, and maybe that comes down to my lack of experience in Angular, so if that's the case, I apologize in advance.

I'm building a pretty basic Angular App, it's just supposed to access the iTunes API and search for songs/movie/etc... and return a few results below. However, whenever I enter a character into the input, I get no results, and an error in the console(I'm using Firefox)

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('itunes-search', ['ngResource']).config(function($sceDelegateProvider){
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        'https://itunes.apple.com/**'
    ]);
});

app.factory('Media', function($resource){
    return $resource('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=:query'),{query: '@query'}, {
        search: {
            method: 'JSONP', 
            params: {
                limit: 3,
                callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK'}
        }
    }
});

app.controller('MediaCtrl',
    function($scope, Media){
        $scope.query = '';
        $scope.$watchCollection('query', function(){
            if ($scope.query.length > 0){
                Media.search({ query: $scope.query}, function(data){
                    $scope.results = data.results;
                });
            } else {
                $scope.results=[];
            }
        });
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>iTunes Search</title>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.9/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="itunes-search" ng-controller="MediaCtrl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

      <div class="page-header">
        <h1>iTunes Search</h1>
      </div>
      <input type="search" ng-model="query" ng-keyup="onKeyupSearch()"
             placeholder="Search for Movies, Music, etc." style="width: 100%;"/>
      <ul ng-repeat="result in results">
        <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        <li>
            <h2>{{result.trackName}}</h2>
            <h3>{{result.artistName}}</h3>
            <img ng-src="{{result.artworkUrl100}}"/>
        </li>
          </span>
        </span>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope I've given enough detail, and if you have any additional resources to help me learn more Angular, I'd really appreciate suggestions. I can add any additional information if I need to.

Thanks again!

Comment: The `Media.search` method should have `search` in lowercase.

Comment: With AngularJS V1.6, you can no longer use the JSON_CALLBACK string as a placeholder for specifying where the callback parameter value should go. Are you sure that the iTunes store supports an obsolete JSONP API? It would be wiser to do that operation with `$http.jsonp`. Using ngResource adds no value and makes the whole thing more difficult to understand, test, debug and maintain.